# What's the difference between <=> and - in a block for sort method?

Tags: ruby, sorting, comparison

I have an array like this:

```
my_array = [1,3,5,5,6,7]
```

to be sorted from the biggest to the smallest. I do these:

1. `my_array.sort { |a,b| b <=> a }`
2. `my_array.sort { |a,b| b - a }`

Both return the same thing: `[7,6,5,5,3,1]`. Can someone explain what the difference is between those two?

Comment: I see you haven't selected an answer.  None of them were helpful to you?

Answer (score 3):

The [document](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-sort) states:

> sort → array
>   sort { |a, b| block } → array
>   Returns an array containing the items in enum sorted, either according to their own <=> method, or by using the results of the supplied block. The block should return -1, 0, or +1 depending on the comparison between a and b. As of Ruby 1.8, the method Enumerable#sort_by implements a built-in Schwartzian Transform, useful when key computation or comparison is expensive.

So there is no official mentioning when the evaluated value of the block is other than `-1`, `0`, or `1`. If what you did works, then it is perhaps working under the principle that negative numbers are regarded as `-1` and positive numbers are regarded as `1`. If that is the case, there is no difference. However, since it is not officially stated so, I think it is safer to use `{|a, b| b <=> a}`

Comment: According to [Ruby MRI/util.c - ruby_qsort()](http://rxr.whitequark.org/mri/source/util.c#306), it cares only about the sign.

Comment: Yes, but MRI is only one of about half a dozen implementations, there's also YARV, MacRuby, JRuby, IronRuby, MagLev, MRuby, Rubinius, … I would *not* depend on the fact that all of those implement something which is not part of the docs or the spec in he same way. That would be a *huge* coincidence.

Answer (score 1):

One subtracts, one uses the items' `<=>` operator.

You're using numbers, `Fixnum` to be precise, so subtracting produces `< 0`, `0`, or `> 0`.

`<=>` for `Fixnum` calls the C routine:

```
if (x == y) return INT2FIX(0);
if (FIXNUM_P(y)) {
    if (FIX2LONG(x) > FIX2LONG(y)) return INT2FIX(1);
    return INT2FIX(-1);
}
```

which returns -1, 0, or 1, which produces the same results–because the sort only checks the sign.

The bottom line is that in *this* case there's no difference, but that's an implementation detail.

Comment: "that's an implementation detail". Another way of saying it might 'splode unexpected. :-)

Comment: @theTinMan I'm in an understate-y mood today, I think it's the haircut.

Comment: "I think it's the haircut." That's what Samson said after listening to Delilah.

Answer (score 0):

It's a kind of trick. The block used in sort an array must return a comparaison result, -1 (a lower than b), 0 (a equal b) , 1 ( a higher than b).

What happens, is that code seems to use the sign of the operation only, and not the value so (b-a) operation return the same sign than b <=> a operation:

```
1-10       -9 # neg
1<=>10     -1 # neg

5-5         0 # eq  
5<=>5       0 # eq 

10-1        9 # pos
10<=>1      1 # pos
```

But I strongly suggest to use the comparaison operator instead of the difference.

Answer (score 0):

It's important to understand what `<=>` is doing, as it's the crux for sorting and comparisons:

The `<=>` operator (AKA "spaceship") tells us whether one value is less-than, equal, or greater-than another, which makes it easy to know when code should swap them. For instance:

```
0 <=> 1 # => -1
1 <=> 1 # => 0
2 <=> 1 # => 1
```

In other words, `-1` means the comparison was less-than, `0` was equal, and `1` was greater-than. Knowing that, code can swap the values one of two ways or ignore swapping.

Using `-` works for numbers, but it's going to have really unexpected results with other data-types, like strings, arrays, hashes, which use `-` differently, if at all.

Read the documentation for the [Comparable](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.3/Comparable.html) module, which makes it really easy to add additional functionally to a class by defining the `<=>(other)` method and to understand what you'll gain by using it.